# TrailRenderer.colorGradient "Print current specs in order to replicate in code"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After reading the API info here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TrailRenderer-colorGradient.html

I am wondering if I can "tune in" my trail renderer in the normal unity interface, print those complicated code parameters, then use that code in my script to change color on triggers, etc.

To clarify, how do I get the information here presented in code:
[[image: Trail Renderer Inspector View]]

I guess I am approaching this from a CSS background.  Is there a Unity colorgradient version of this website:
https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Can I make the script print the characteristics of the trail renderer (for the purpose of replicating it elsewhere in my code)?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9XcZ.png)

Much appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are asking... What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want an object's trail renderer to change gradient pattern as it enters triggers.  I'd like to be able to use the standard unity interface to design my gradients, then get a script to print out the "array's code" so I can plug it back in, like the unity API example illustrates.

Comment: Look here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TrailRenderer-colorGradient.html

Comment: I'd like to make a custom thing in this part of the above link:

Comment: gradient.SetKeys(
            new GradientColorKey[] { new GradientColorKey(Color.green, 0.0f), new GradientColorKey(Color.red, 1.0f) },
            new GradientAlphaKey[] { new GradientAlphaKey(alpha, 0.0f), new GradientAlphaKey(alpha, 1.0f) }
        );

Comment: And they get complicated... so how can I make one in the interface, then get c# to tell me what the way it describes the thing I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure if I understood the question but I'll give it a shot.

As I understand you want to have a component on every trigger object where you can define different gradient settings for each.

And I assume by `Unity interface` you mean the Inspector.

So something like e.g.

```
public class GradientSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GradientColorKey[] colorKeys;
    public GradientAlphaKey[] alphaKeys;  
}
```

Put this on the trigger object(s) and adjust the settings via the Inspector. At beginning they should be empty arrays so to add elements just enter the wanted element count in the `size` property of both arrays.

And wherever you have the Collision implemented on your TrailRenderer object

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    var gradientSetter = other.GetComponent<GradientSetter>();
    if(!gradientSetter) return;

    gradient.SetKeys(gradientSetter.colorKeys, gradientSetter.alphaKeys);

    ...
}
```

---

I'm assuming `GradientColorKey` and `GradientAlphaKey` are `Serializable`. If you implement this but they don't show up in the Inspector let me know, then you'll have to make a wrapper class for them. (I can't test it right now)

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*